# ¿Como parsear esta fecha? - "210827145531Z" - PHP

Tags: php, date

Estoy obteniendo una fecha desde un archivo, y hay 2 tipos de esta:

```
["validFrom"]=> string(13) "210827145531Z"
["validTo"]=> string(13) "230827145531Z"
["validFrom_time_t"]=> int(1630076131)
["validTo_time_t"]=> int(1693148131)
```

Los arreglos que son INT no tengo problemas en parsearlos, solo uso el date()

```
echo date("Y-m-d", 1630076131);
//Output: 2021-08-27
```

Pero los que terminan en Z son los que me tienen confundidos, pensé en usar strtotime(), pero esto no resulta en nada.

```
echo date("Y-m-d", strtotime('210827145531Z'));
1970-01-01
```

Comment: La Z tiene pinta de ser lo de la hora del meridiano de Greenwitch u hora UTC

Comment: Yup yup, pero lo que busco es como parsearla

Answer (score 6, accepted):

La clase `DateTime` tiene un método llamado [`createFromFormat()`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.createfromformat.php) que es bastante útil para casos como este.

Simplemente le indicas el formato en que está tu fecha, y la clase te creará un objeto `DateTime` con todas las ventajas que ello implica.

Si analizamos tu cadena: `210827145531Z` podemos concluir que el formato de la misma es el siguiente: `ymdHise` a saber:

- `y` : año en dos dígitos
- `m` : mes en dos dígitos
- `H` : hora en formato 24 horas
- `i` : minutos en formato `00`
- `s` : segundos en formato `00`
- `e` : zona horaria

Entonces, construimos un formato y lo pasamos como primer parámetro (ver enlace sobre la descripción del método y lo que significa cada letra en los formatos ... hay bastante más formatos posibles):

```
$mDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('ymdHise', '210827145531Z');
var_dump($mDate);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(DateTime)#1 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-08-27 14:55:31.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(2)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(1) "Z"
}
```

Repito: tienes ahí en `$mDate` un objeto [`DateTime`](https://www.php.net/manual/es/class.datetime.php), con toda la potencialidad de los objetos. Significa que puedes usar `$mDate` para hacer desde las cosas más simples (mostrarla fecha/hora en determinados formatos) hasta las más complejas (como comparar, modificar, calcular intervalos o períodos, etc).

---

#### Post-Data

Si te interesa usar tus valores numéricos para crear la fecha también puedes hacerlo.

Esos valores son una *marca temporal de Unix* (timestamp) y el constructor de `DateTime` [acepta esos valores en primer parámetro](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.formats.compound.php) (debes poner primero `@`), y en segundo, le pasas la zona horaria que deseas.

Por ejemplo:

```
$ts=1630076131;
$mDate = new DateTime("@$ts",new DateTimeZone('Z')); 
var_dump($mDate);
```

**Salida:**

```
object(DateTime)#2 (3) {
  ["date"]=>
  string(26) "2021-08-27 14:55:31.000000"
  ["timezone_type"]=>
  int(1)
  ["timezone"]=>
  string(6) "+00:00"
}
```

Para más detalles, consulta el [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/datetime.construct.php).

Comment: Solo una duda, que me surge a partir de la respuesta de abulafalia.... ¿Como se si es 2021 o 1921? Solo ocurre y ya ?

Comment: @Excorpion interesante apunte. Si lees el enlace que puse en la pregunta verás lo que dice el Manual al respecto, cuando explica el formato **`y`**: *Una representación de dos dígitos de un año (el cual se asume que esté **en el rango 1970-2069**, inclusive)*. Por tanto, el `21` no puede ser nunca `1921` porque queda fuera del rango de Epoch.

Comment: Gracias por todo Cedano

Comment: De nada, @Excorpion, lo mejor sería, si pudieras, producir el año con cuatro dígitos en el origen, y cambiar la `y` por la `Y` en el parámetro. Así, no habría ningún problema con el año. Por ejemplo, si tuvieras esto: **`20210827145531Z`** o esto **`19210827145531Z`** usarías el formato: **`YmdHise`** para crear tu objeto.

Answer (score 4):

Tienes que separar la cadena de 2 en 2 caracteres y descubres así que se trata del año, mes, día, hora, minuto y segundo concatenados:

21 08 27 14 55 31 Z

Así que puedes usar esos valores una vez divididos en un array (mediante `str_split()`) como parámetros de `mktime()`, para crear con ello un timestamp unix que ya sería un número como los otros que sí sabes usar.

Es decir, por ejemplo:

```php
$s = "210827145531Z";
$partes = str_split($s, 2);
$timestamp = mktime($partes[3], $partes[4], $partes[5], $partes[1], $partes[2], "20".$partes[0]);
echo date("Y-m-d", $timestamp);
```

Sale:

```
2021-08-27
```

**Notas**

- El orden en que hay que pasar las partes a [`mktime()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mktime.php) es hora, minutos, segundos, mes, dia, año.
- Esto solo va a funcionar bien si la centuria es "20", pues la he añadido "manualmente"

Comment: Pero igual estás agregando un "20" delante, lo que no cubriria si la fecha es antigua, como 1982 cierto ?

Comment: Sí, acababa de editar la respuesta para aclarar eso. En cualquier caso ya que la centuria no viene en la cadena, solo nos queda "adivinar"